# pdf mcq to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to convert text like this from a pdf into a pandas dataframe?
text:

1. The theory of comparative cost advantage theory was Introduced by-----
   a) Alfred Marshall b) David Ricardo
   c) Taussig d) Heberler
2. The Ricardo’s comparative cost theory is based on which of the following assumption
   a) Common Market b) Equal cost
   c) Monopoly d) Free Trade

expected df:

```
The theory of comparative cost advantage theory was Introduced by-----                  Alfred Marshall     David Ricardo     Taussig     Heberler
The Ricardo’s comparative cost theory is based on which of the following assumption     Common Market       Equal cost        Monopoly    Free Trade
```

Comment: Are you able to extract the text from pdf?

Comment: @AdityaK yes thats not a problem for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Row by row is delimited by newline
- column by column by a regular expression split

```
rawtxt = """The theory of comparative cost advantage theory was Introduced by----- a) Alfred Marshall b) David Ricardo c) Taussig d) Heberler
The Ricardo’s comparative cost theory is based on which of the following assumption a) Common Market b) Equal cost c) Monopoly d) Free Trade"""

df = pd.DataFrame({"rawtxt":rawtxt.split("\n")})
df.rawtxt.str.split(r"[a-z]\)").apply(pd.Series)
```

#### output

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | The theory of comparative cost advantage theory was Introduced by----- | Alfred Marshall | David Ricardo | Taussig | Heberler |
| 1 | The Ricardo’s comparative cost theory is based on which of the following assumption | Common Market | Equal cost | Monopoly | Free Trade |

Comment: You can also use the `expand=True` parameter for `str.split()` instead of chaining it to `apply(pd.Series)` which is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to extract the text from the PDF with each sentence/question separated by a new line, you can make use of Regex like this:

```
import re

regex = r"(.+)(a\).+).+(b\).+).+(c\).+).+(d\).+)"
pdf_txt = """The theory of comparative cost advantage theory was Introduced by----- a) Alfred Marshall b) David Ricardo c) Taussig d) Heberler\n 
            The Ricardo’s comparative cost theory is based on which of the following assumption a) Common Market b) Equal cost c) Monopoly d) Free Trade\n"""

matches = re.finditer(regex, pdf_txt, re.MULTILINE)

data = {1 : [], 2 : [], 3 : [], 4 : [], 5 : []}

for match_num, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    for group_num in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        data[group_num + 1].append(match.group(group_num + 1))
    

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['Question', 'A', "B", "C", "D"]
print(df.head())
```